# Transaction and TransactionScope isolation

Tags: c#, linq, transactions, sql-server-ce

I have to add to my database a lot of information. Adding this information takes about 5–7 minutes. And I need to add transaction.

I tried this:

```
try { 
    db.Connection.Open();
    db.Transaction = db.Connection.BeginTransaction(); 
    UpdateTable1();
    UpdateBigTable2();
    ...
    db.Transaction.Commit(); 
} catch {
    db.Transaction.Rollback();  
}
```

But when my database is updating, I cannot read or do anything with my DB.

I tried to set `IsolationLevel`, but any of it didn't help.

I tried this:

```
using (var ts = new TransactionScope()) {
    UpdateTable1();
    ts.Complete();
}
```

But program crashes after 2–3 minutes.

This solution didn't help too:

```
var transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions();
transactionOptions.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.Serializable;
transactionOptions.Timeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
using (var ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOptions))
{
    ...
}
```

I have get access to my database, when it's updating, if I set `TransactionScopeOption.Suppress`
But in this case Transaction doesn't work.

Comment: When you update is not only an update command but is something with inserts from an external source i'd recommend you should try SQLBulkCopy into a staging database and then copy from there to your actual database. This should be much faster. (I once accomplished factor 3000-6000 by this method).

Comment: @TGlatzer full real world code sample using ***SQLBulkCopy*** in transactionscope? ***Isolation level*** ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you start a transaction that manipulates lots of records, and takes a long time to complete, then as a direct result competing operations will be blocked. This is *especially* true for "serializable" transactions, since they take the most locks (including key-range locks etc). This is the nature of a transaction; it is the I in ACID.

Options:

- don't do everything in one huge transaction
- have your read operations intentionally read *past* the locks (this is hugely double-edged - can be fine, but can cause big problems - treat with caution) - for example `NOLOCK` or `READ UNCOMMITTED`.
- on full SQL server (not CE), try using snapshot isolation

Comment: I have long transaction for insert more 3000 records using ***Serializable***, and I get timeout errors.

Comment: @Kiquenet yes, I can imagine you would; that's a lot of work

Answer (score 1):

```
using (var trans = new TransactionScope(
 TransactionScopeOption.Required, 
    new TransactionOptions
    {
        IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted
    }
))
{
    // Your LINQ to SQL query goes here where you read some data from DB
}
```

while updating tables (inserting, deleting or updating), they become locked, so if you want to read the data, which is not yet commit, so, you can use Transaction IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted to allow dirty reads

Comment: additional note for the OP: it is the *competing queries* (the ones that are being blocked) that need to cheat like this

Comment: result is exception with message
"Transaction specified for TransactionScope, is set IsolationLevel, other than the value requested for the area.
Parameter name: transactionOptions.IsolationLevel"

Comment: this must be separated from your previous transaction, then it will work

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this ?

```
transactionOptions.Timeout = TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout;
```